# Where does Eclipse store SSL keys?

Tags: eclipse, jira

I'm trying to use the JIRA dashboard plugin from tigris.org to connect to our in-house JIRA server, which has an invalid SSL certificate.  I'd like to import the certificate into the keystore used by this plugin, whether that's the Eclipse keystore (which is where?) or its own.

If it helps, here's the error message:

> sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

How can I go about finding the keystore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that Eclipse doesn't store keys, it uses the jssecacerts keystore that is provided by the JVM

Comment: where do you need to put that file if you generate your own